# Noun Phrases and For each

Tags: noun-phrases

In the following sentence, what would be the noun phrases?

> A gift for each one of the students Jerry, Max and Tom.

I think it's:

[A gift] for each one of [the students Jerry, max and Tom]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
 A gift for each one of the students Jerry, Max and Tom.
```

is not a sentence!   There is no verb.   So it's a fragment or clause.  What kind of fragment is it?   It's a noun phrase!

Here are ***all*** of the noun phrases, indicated in your notation:

```
[[A gift] for [each one of [the students [[Jerry], [[Max] and [Tom]]]]]]
```

This looks complicated!   But noun phrases often "nest" - they contain each other.   Here they are listed out individually, you can look at each and verify it is actually a noun phrase:

```
A gift
Jerry
Max
Tom
Max and Tom
Jerry, Max, and Tom
the students Jerry, Max, and Tom
each one of the students Jerry, Max, and Tom
A gift for each one of the students Jerry, Max, and Tom
```

Go through this list and check that each one can function as a subject, for example with "____  is/are here":

```
 Max is here.
 A gift is here.
```

and so forth...